# Off-setting a Google Map Icon using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google Map on my website and I am also using a Custom marker to mark the location of the business. I want to bring the icon about 100px to the left as it's currently center of the map... How can I do this?

My code:

```
function initMap() {
    var LatLng = {
        lat: REMOVED, lng: REMOVED
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: LatLng
    });

    var image = 'REMOVED';

    var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've almost done. The problem is that you are centering the map in the same position than your marker.

So, set another `LatLang` for your marker or center the map in another position.

```
var markerLatLang={lat: WHATEVER, lng: WHATEVER}

var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerLatLang,
    map: map,
    icon: image
});
```

[Checkout this for further information](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers).